# javascript onclick get the div id?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to get the ids of the 2 div tags on clicking the button, using javascript?

```
<div id="main">
<div id="content">
</div>
<button onclick="function();">show it</button>
</div>
```

I have 2 div tags here. The 1st div is in the main div while the content div is inside the main div and the button is inside the main div as well.

Is it possible to get the ***main*** and ***content*** id of the 2 div tags on clicking the button?

EXPECTED OUTPUT when I press the button:

> ```
> alert: main
> alert: content
> ```

Comment: To get an element by id: `Element.getElementById("main");`. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: He wants to find out the ID,

Comment: when i click the button i want to get the id of the 2 divs.

Comment: You know the ordering of the HTML. So you can just get the parent nodes and then get the ID attribute of each node.

Comment: how about i have alot of divs and i have a button inside of each divs i want to get the id of the div when i click the button of what inside of the div.

Comment: Can people stop voting this down, this is a reasonable question. Not everybody goes though the same path of learning as you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass the element to the function. Then you can use `parentNode` to get the `DIV` that contains the button. From there, you can use `querySelector` to find the first `DIV` in the parent.

```js
function showIt(element) {
  var parent = element.parentNode;
  alert(parent.id);
  var content = parent.querySelector("div");
  alert(content.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="content">
  </div>
  <button onclick="showIt(this);">show it</button>
</div>
<div id="main2">
  <div id="content2">
  </div>
  <button onclick="showIt(this);">show it</button>
</div>
<div id="main3">
  <div id="content3">
  </div>
  <button onclick="showIt(this);">show it</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are going to use `querySelector`, you can also use `element.previousElementSibling` or `element.parentNode.firstElementChild`, which I think would be better suited in this case.

Comment: Good point, I'm not very familiar with those properties. My first attempt used `firstChild`, and it was failing because of the text node before the DIV, so I switched to `querySelector`.

Comment: Ah yeah, those sometimes return text nodes. The xElementY properties always return element nodes.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/myel/a9d5y9gs/ 

i have code added as i implement your answer but im having an error on it it keeps duplicating.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        var id = divs[i].getAttribute('id');
        alert(id);
    }
};
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/jm5okh69/1/**

Comment: how about i have alot of divs and i have a button inside of each divs i want to get the id of the div when i click the button of what inside of the div

Comment: This will work, but it's going to be really fragile. Not an issue with the solution, but an issue with the question. Are there other <divs> on the page? If so, you'll get their IDs as well.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in all browsers and uses the cleaner `.id` method.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.onclick = getIDs;

function getIDs(){
 var id,divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {        
         id = divs[i].id //  .id is a method 
        alert(id);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <button id="button">show it</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Myel Rather than trying to approach a solution can you please simply  describe what you are trying to do in detail without being technical.