# Get the specific div id from an onclick event (Pure JS no Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html

When I try the code referenced in [SO #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112838/javascript-onclick-get-the-div-id), I get the console logging a blank string:

```
installChoices() {
        var choices = this.game.page.options;
        for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
            var choice = choices[i];
            var choiceDiv = document.createElement("choice" + i);
            choiceDiv.innerText = choice[0];
            choiceDiv.onclick = function() {
                console.log(this.id);
            }
            this.choicesContainer.appendChild(choiceDiv);
        }

    }
```

I want to bind to my class function clicked

```
installChoices() {
        var choices = this.game.page.options;
        for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
            var choice = choices[i];
            var choiceDiv = document.createElement("choice" + i);
            choiceDiv.innerText = choice[0];
            choiceDiv.onclick = this.clicked;
            this.choicesContainer.appendChild(choiceDiv);
        }

    }

    clicked(e) {
        console.log(e.parentNode); //this is undefined
        console.log(e.srcElement);
    }
```

But that shows undefined. When I log srcElement, I get the full element

```
<choice0>path 1</choice0>
```

I want to get just the div id when I click, so I can parse that and do logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend the following approach, as it is the standard:

```
//assign the event
choiceDiv.addEventListener('click', clicked)

//define the listener
function clicked(event) {
    console.log(event.currentTarget)
}
```

**update:**

I'm tempted to offer a fix to your code, because I don't think you're achieving what are you trying to actually do:

```
function installChoices() {
    var choices = this.game.page.options;
    for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
        var choice = choices[i];
        var choiceDiv = document.createElement("div");
        choiceDiv.id = "choice" + i;
        choiceDiv.innerText = choice[0];
        choiceDiv.addEventListener("click", clicked);
        this.choicesContainer.appendChild(choiceDiv);
    }
}

function clicked(ev) {
    console.log(ev.currentTarget.id); //this will log "choice0"
}
```

Comment: `event.srcElement || event.currentTarget || event.target` for cross browser

Comment: you have the clicked function, I should use this.clicked since I'm in a class, correct? Does that affect anything? (Testing your code now!)

Comment: Thanks so much, that works! I'll use addEventListener int he future that works great.

Comment: How can I pass in a reference to mycurrent object, since this is being overriden?

Comment: @self: He's using `.addEventListener()`, so that's unnecessary, and it's not really correct since `event.currentTarget` isn't necessarily the same as `event.target` and `event.srcElement`.

Comment: yeah well `event` global variable doesn't exist in firefox, so `event` is just a  variable name of the arguments of the second argument which is a function to the `addEventListener`

Comment: How can I pass in a reference to my current object, eg extra params?

Comment: @self: Not sure what you mean. He's not using the `event` global variable, and I was talking about the `.srcElement` and `.target` properties. There's just no need for those to make it cross browser.

Comment: I got it with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256754/how-to-pass-arguments-to-addeventlistener-listener-function

Comment: the fact is that one of those properties aren't standard and I don't have time to look it up in the W3 spec

Answer (score 0):

Your "clicked" function are receiving an Event rather than a HTML Element. This is the default behavior when an onClick event triggered.

The click event have a srcElement property, indicating the source element the click event occurred upon. This event object have no parentNode property.

Use e.srcElement.parentNode instead.

BTW, in the SO #1 example, it assign "showIt(this)" to onClick, so browser pass "this", the target element rather than the event object,  to the onClick function.

Comment: Ah, thank you for clarifying the passing "this", testing that.

Comment: When I try choiceDiv.onclick = this.clicked.bind(this);, it remains a mouse event function not an element

Comment: So I can get e.srcElement, but logging e.srcElement.id is still empty string

Comment: revisited your question, it seems you need to get the id, not the parent node, use e.srcElement.id can do the trick.

Comment: you haven't assign an id to srcElement in code. Assign it first, use choiceDiv.id.

Comment: document.createElement("choice") . the createElement expect a tag, not an id.  So you need to assign an id to the created element in code